# What is the iterator feature for in Terraform's for_each?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to understand the `iterator` feature of the `for_each` in Terraform 0.12. The [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html) say:

**Iterator:**

> The `iterator` argument (optional) sets the name of a temporary variable that represents the current element of the complex value. If omitted, the name of the variable defaults to the label of the dynamic block ...

But I can't find any code examples that uses this feature and I can't get my head around what it is for. I have read the Terraform 0.12 [preview](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each) but it is not mentioned there, and I found some GitHub issues (e.g. [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17179) one) but can't find clues there either.

Is it just for improving readability? I would really appreciate a code example and explanation that goes beyond what I can find in the docs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically in various languages like Python, Ruby, C++, Javascript, Groovy, etc. you can establish a temporary variable within a lambda (especially if it is iterative) that stores the temporary value per iteration within the lambda. In some languages (e.g. Groovy), there is a default name for this variable, or you can set one yourself (i.e. default variable name in Groovy is `it`). For example, in Groovy we have:

```
strings.each() {
  print it
}
```

would print the content of the `string` variable assignment (assuming it can be cast to String). The following code has the exact same functionality:

```
strings.each() { a_string ->
  print a_string
}
```

where we have explicitly named the temporary variable as `a_string`. This is analogous to the `iterator` argument in your question. So in Terraform, we see an example in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks):

```
resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  name = "example" # can use expressions here

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.service_ports
    content {
      from_port = ingress.value
      to_port   = ingress.value
      protocol  = "tcp"
    }
  }
}
```

According to the documentation:

> If omitted, the name of the variable defaults to the label of the dynamic block

and the name above is `ingress` (notice it is the label specified adjacent to the `dynamic` block). Sure enough, we see the name of the temporary variable above is `ingress` and it is being accessed via `ingress.value`. To utilize the functionality of `iterator` to rename this temporary variable, we can do something like the below.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  name = "example" # can use expressions here

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.service_ports
    iterator = service_port
    content {
      from_port = service_port.value
      to_port   = service_port.value
      protocol  = "tcp"
    }
  }
}
```

thus renaming the temporary variable storing the element of `var.service_ports` in each iteration within the lambda from default name `ingress` to `service_port`. The primary added value I see in this (and likewise when I use it in Groovy for Jenkins Pipeline libraries) is to provide a more clear name for the temporary variable storing the value to improve readability.

Comment: @AlexHarvey It really depends. If the label you choose for the `dynamic` block also well describes the value iterated over, then you should not need it. If it does not, then you have the option to rename it. This is a "use your best judgement" kind of situation as well as "better to have something and not need it then need it and not have it."

Comment: The trick for me was NOT to put quotes around the iterator value. ;-)