# 2 different ways of doing terraform dynamic statement, what's the difference

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have come across 2 terraform dynamic syntax, just wondering what's the difference?

```
dynamic "storage_account" {
    for_each = var.storage_account == null ? {} : var.storage_account
    content {
      name         = storage_account.value.name
      type         = storage_account.value.type
      account_name = storage_account.value.account_name
      share_name   = storage_account.value.share_name
      access_key   = storage_account.value.access_key
      mount_path   = storage_account.value.mount_path
    }
  }

dynamic "backup" {
    for_each = var.app_service_backup != null ? [1] : []
    content {
      name                = var.app_service_backup.name
      enabled             = true
      storage_account_url = var.app_service_backup.storage_account_url
      schedule {
        frequency_interval = var.app_service_backup.frequency_interval
        frequency_unit     = var.app_service_backup.frequency_unit
      }
    }
  }
```

and variable is

```
variable "storage_account" {
  description = <<EOF
  (Optional) - One or more storage_account blocks as defined below.

  (Required) name - The name of the storage account identifier.
  (Required) type - The type of storage. Possible values are AzureBlob and AzureFiles.
  (Required) account_name - The name of the storage account.
  (Required) share_name - The name of the file share (container name, for Blob storage).
  (Required) access_key - The access key for the storage account.
  (Required) mount_path - The path to mount the storage within the site's runtime environment.
  EOF
  type = map(object({
    name         = string
    type         = string
    account_name = string
    share_name   = string
    access_key   = string
    mount_path   = string
  }))

  default = null
}


variable "app_service_backup" {
  description = <<EOF
    (Optional) - The app service backup block supports the following:

    (Required) name - Specifies the name for this Backup.
    (Required) storage_account_url - The SAS URL to a Storage Container where Backups should be saved.
    (Required) frequency_interval - Sets how often the backup should be executed.
    (Required) frequency_unit - Sets the unit of time for how often the backup should be executed. Possible values are Day or Hour.
  EOF

  type = object({
    name                = string
    storage_account_url = string
    frequency_interval  = number
    frequency_unit      = string

  })

  default = null
}
```

notice how the first dynamic storage_account it's using things like storage_account.value.name
and second "backup" is using var.app_service_backup.name

for the second one, can I use backup.value.name?

Comment: Do you get any errors with the code?

Comment: no error, its running fine. Just wondering whats the difference with 2 format

Comment: @Marcin well answers the primary question. Your secondary question appears to be very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442607/what-is-the-iterator-feature-for-in-terraforms-for-each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have [Conditional Expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/conditionals) in TF such as

`condition ? true_val : false_val`

`true_val` and `false_val` must be of **same type**.

So in your first example:

```
for_each = var.storage_account == null ? {} : var.storage_account
```

`var.storage_account` is map, so the `true_val` must also be a `map`. In this case its an empty `map` `{}`. Since this map does not have any elements, `for_each` will not run.

In your second example maps could also be used, but lists are shorter to write, so you have (just a convention):

```
 for_each = var.app_service_backup != null ? [1] : []
```

where `[]` is an empty list, and `[1]` is a list with one element. So `for_each` will run only once. The value of the element in the list `[1]` is `1`, but it really does not matter. It can be any value, as long as length of the list is not zero.

**UPDATE**.

You can't use `backup.value.name` in the second example, because in that case `backup.value` is literally `1` as its the value from `[1]`. Also it does not make sense to forcibly change your `for_each` to use `var.app_service_backup`, as its just a single value. There is no iteration needed for it. So you just access it directly.

Comment: thanks @Marcin， is it possible to write the second one content like the first one?  Something like backup.value.name

Comment: @RogerChen Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You can make new question specific to that problem.  Your current question is about "what's the difference" between the two for_each statements.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, actually my question actuallly states “ notice how the first dynamic storage_account it's using things like storage_account.value.name and second "backup" is using var.app_service_backup.name. for the second one, can i use backup.value.name? “. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Cheers , it makes sense now. Actually i dont see much point of using dynamic block for the second example